# Who is trying to access NTFS?

Tags: ntfs, kernel-extensions

A **long** time ago, I installed Paragon's NTFS drivers.  But I no longer any NTFS drives (since almost as long).

But yesterday, I had a few apps open, and GraphicConverter had the focus, when this popped up:[image]

There is no reason I can think of for any program that was running to suddenly try to do anything with NTFS.  **How can I identify "A program" when it does something like this?**

Comment: Paragon 'phones home' all the time to check for a valid license. That may have required it to load a component.

Comment: That sounds like a good possibility.  Although, if that's from "check for updates" it's odd that I can't remember it happening before in many months.

Comment: I don't have hard facts on this, only that I have *one* license for it, because I only need it about once a year, if that, yet if I try to use it on two computers it shouts at me. My solution is to keep it blocked on Little Snitch unless I need to use it.